# Creating Azure custom log failed with authentication error

Tags: azure-monitor

I am follwing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-api and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-code?tabs=python to create a custom log in Azure, using Python. But it failed with error:

The authentication token provided does not have access to ingest data for the data collection rule with immutable Id 'dcr-xxxxxxxxxxx' PipelineAccessResult: AccessGranted: False, IsRbacPresent: False, IsDcrDceBindingValid: , DcrArmId: /subscriptions/59xxxx/resourceGroups/DevStack/providers/Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules/hlgcustomlogrule, Message: Required autorization action was not found for tenantId 82xxxx objectId xxxxx on resourceId /subscriptions/59xxxxx/resourceGroups/DevStack/providers/Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules/hlgcustomlogrule ConfigurationId: dcr-xxxx..
Code: OperationFailed

Here is my code:

```
# information needed to send data to the 

    DCR endpoint
    dce_endpoint = "https://myendpoint.ingest.monitor.azure.com" # ingestion endpoint of the Data Collection Endpoint object
    dcr_immutableid = "dcr-xxxxx" # immutableId property of the Data Collection Rule
    stream_name = "Custom-xxxx_CL" #name of the stream in the DCR that represents the destination table
client = LogsIngestionClient(endpoint=dce_endpoint, credential=credential, logging_enable=True)
time_generated = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
body = {
    "TimeGenerated": time_generated,
    "UserName": "Tester Two",
    "UserId": "tester02@companyone.com",
    "Description": "Exported confidential data"
}
client.upload(rule_id=dcr_immutableid, stream_name=stream_name, logs=body)
```

Can anybody help me?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The error mainly points to the Authorization issue (after the authentication has taken place).

Based on the details in the question, it seems that the step to "Assign required permission in DCR to the newly registered app) was skipped. See the following link for more details and steps to add permission - [Assign permissions to the DCR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/tutorial-logs-ingestion-portal#assign-permissions-to-the-dcr)

Also, if you have recently created the table and have assigned permission, you may see this error for a couple of minutes. You could try waiting for 15-20 minutes before trying to send data again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. After I followed it to add permission, my code was executed successfully without error. But I cannot find any data in the Azure custom log table I created. Can you please let me know what I should do to create a custom log properly?  Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If you are not getting error anymore, the values would be getting inserted into the LA's custom logs. However, since it was a new table with values getting inserted, it takes a while for this to be visible in logs. You should have logs visible now and it should be smoother operation henceforth.